# Host CPU is Missing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio on my computer today and am trying to run my first application but the Simulator isn't loading up. I tried increasing the ram and that didn't do anything so I moved it back to default. Here is what gets printed out every time I try to run the app.

```
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSE4.2 POPCNT
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
VCPU shutdown request
```

Comment: I would suggest just attaching a physical device.  Or trying Genymotion.  The build in simulator is more hassle than its worth.

Comment: Related bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78646

Comment: ok I thanks I was about to do so but wanted to see if I could get this to work without having to use a separate device.

Comment: The error message seems to point that your cpu doesn't have SSE4 capabilities. Try setting a 32 bit emulator, i.e. just 'x86' and not 'x86_64'.

Comment: Please, uswer1241, if my comment drove you to your solution please alert me. I would like to create a full response to your question in order to get my precious points here at StackOverflow, with you signing this as the correct answer, to upgrade my reputation. Thank you.

Comment: I do have 64 bit architecture. I am trying it out right now @statosdotcom

Comment: Here you can confirm if your cpu has SSE4 and POPCNT features: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/CPU.html . Another way to find out is to use some software like CPU-Z that shows the correct specs of your CPU. Thank you

Comment: @statosdotcom I have a mid 2010 macbook

Comment: It seems you have an Intel Core 2 Duo there. And it supports SSE4, but i'm afraid not POPCNT instruction... You can read some complains about it here: https://community.remedygames.com/forum/games/quantum-break/windows-10-help-issues/263302-today-s-sse-update-fix-a-cpu-features-missing-dialog-box

Well, try to certify yourself that this is your CPU (the Intel Core 2 Duo) and google and Stack to find a workaround.

For a while you could try another Android API in your emulator, yet using x86_64 or try the same API with x86 only, not 64. Good luck!

Comment: even those options aren't available I can't find a 32 bit emulator and tried using a x86_64. What other android API is there that I can use and where could I get it?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using an older CPU? Like what @statosdotcom said, download a 32 bit image (x86) instead of x86_64.

[image]

Also be sure to update HAXM if you haven't. You might need to uninstall then reinstall it through the SDK Manager.

Comment: Yes... but hey at least flag my comment :D Thanks and congrats.